# iOS 7 Status Bar mixing in with view

Tags: ios

I am creating an application that will work in both iOS 6 and iOS 7. I have a view with a header image at the top. In iOS6 it works fine as it doesn't cover or interfere with the status bar at the top of the screen. However, in iOS 7 the view mixes in with the status bar and it looks terrible. I would need to know how to rectify this without it affecting iOS 6?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your view containing elements in Interface Builder.
2. Select Size Inspector tab from right menu.
3. in iOS 6/7 Deltas, give -20 in Delta-Y and 20 in Delta-height.

NOTE: not applicable using Auto-layouts.

Comment: How would I go about doing this programmatically as this class does not have a .xib file?